# problem connecting cloud run to postgresql 11 database

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to connect my Cloud run container to my PostgreSQL 11 database using this connection string

```
postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@/db?host=/cloudsql/project-name:region:dbinstance
```

when I try to run my container it will give back this error

```
2019-10-24 13:30:53.910 CEST sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused

2019-10-24 13:30:53.910 CEST Is the server running locally and accepting

2019-10-24 13:30:53.910 CEST connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/project-name:region:dbinstance/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

2019-10-24 13:30:53.910 CEST(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I've also tried to use this connection string

```
postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@/db?unix_socket=/cloudsql/project-name:region:dbinstance
```

that returned this error message

```
2019-10-24 11:11:43.733 CESTsqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) invalid dsn: invalid connection option "unix_socket"

2019-10-24 11:11:43.733 CEST(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

2019-10-24 11:11:44.469 CESTContainer called exit(1).
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For connecting to a Cloud SQL instance from Cloud Run, Google has [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run) guide. You can find the Python snippet in there.

As the documentation states, the PostgreSQL standard requires the Unix socket to have a .s.PGSQL.5432 suffix in the socket path. Some libraries apply this suffix automatically, but others require you to specify the socket path as follows:

Comment: my libary applies it automatically :)